# Install requirements.txt in a specific python env path?

Tags: python, linux, conda

How can I do a pip install requirements.txt to a specific python installation?

This is the location of the python installation:

`/opt/conda/envs/prod/bin/python`

And my requirements.txt is here:

`/home/jupyter/services/requirements.txt`

Can I just do something like `/opt/conda/envs/prod/bin/python pip install -r /home/jupyter/ml_gcp_services/requirements.txt`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using conda to manage your Python environments. You first have to activate your environment, check out the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) for how to do it and what it actually does. It looks like your environment is called `prod`, so you would activate it using:

```
conda activate prod
```

Once activated you can simply install your requirements.txt as you would usually do:

```
pip install -r <path/to/requirements.txt>
```

The packages will then be installed into your environment.